# Get countries (in multiple languages) based on the given ISO

Tags: country-codes

I´m building a django application and I try to get a list of countries (which can also contain countries in multiple languages) based on the iso given as the input. Let´s consider the following scenario:

```
"iso": "AU",
"countries": ["Croatia","Egypt","Australia","Griechenland","Australien","Ausztrália"]
```

In the given case, the result should be:

```
"matched_countries": ["Australia","Australien","Ausztrália"]
```

I can think of a solution where having a map of all countries and their corresponding ISO codes. But, how can I do this in all languages included? Manual selection of all names would be a though work; is there any tool that could be used for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful:
https://stefangabos.github.io/world_countries/

Download country info in JSON and make a function which searches inside JSON and returns needed countries.

You may want to manipulate the JSON so that querying and returning data is as easy as possible. For example, you could restructure it so that at the first level the ISO code is a key and value is a dictionary of countries:

```
{
"af": {
  "ar": "أفغانستان",
  "bg": "Афганистан",
  "cs": "Afghánistán",
  "da": "Afghanistan",
  "de": "Afghanistan",
  "el": "Αφγανιστάν",
  "en": "Afghanistan",
  "es": "Afganistán",
  "et": "Afganistan",
  "eu": "Afganistan",
  "fi": "Afganistan",
  "fr": "Afghanistan",
  "hu": "Afganisztán",
  "it": "Afghanistan",
  "ja": "アフガニスタン",
  "ko": "아프가니스탄",
  "lt": "Afganistanas",
  "nl": "Afghanistan",
  "no": "Afghanistan",
  "pl": "Afganistan",
  "pt": "Afeganistão",
  "ro": "Afganistan",
  "ru": "Афганистан",
  "sk": "Afganistan",
  "sv": "Afghanistan",
  "th": "อัฟกานิสถาน",
  "uk": "Афганістан",
  "zh": "阿富汗",
  "zh-tw": "阿富汗"
},
"al": {
  "ar": "ألبانيا",
  "bg": "Албания",
  "cs": "Albánie",
  "da": "Albanien",
  "de": "Albanien",
  "el": "Αλβανία",
  "en": "Albania",
  "es": "Albania",
  "et": "Albaania",
  "eu": "Albania",
  "fi": "Albania",
  "fr": "Albanie",
  "hu": "Albánia",
  "it": "Albania",
  "ja": "アルバニア",
  "ko": "알바니아",
  "lt": "Albanija",
  "nl": "Albanië",
  "no": "Albania",
  "pl": "Albania",
  "pt": "Albânia",
  "ro": "Albania",
  "ru": "Албания",
  "sk": "Albánsko",
  "sv": "Albanien",
  "th": "แอลเบเนีย",
  "uk": "Албанія",
  "zh": "阿尔巴尼亚",
  "zh-tw": "阿爾巴尼亞"
}
}
```

Writing functions returning desired values is quite straightforward:

```
import json

cfile = open('countries.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") # Read country data from text file
country_data = json.load(cfile)
cfile.close()

# Returns all countries
def return_countries(iso):  # Use two digit ISO code
  return country_data[iso]

# Returns country name in [lang] language
def return_country(iso, lang):  # Use two digit ISO code and desired language
  return country_data[iso][lang]
```

Examples of outputs:

Function return_countries:

```
print(return_countries('af'))
```

Output:

```
{'ar': 'أفغانستان', 'bg': 'Афганистан', 'cs': 'Afghánistán', 'da': 'Afghanistan', 'de': 'Afghanistan', 'el': 'Αφγανιστάν', 'en': 'Afghanistan', 'es': 'Afganistán', 'et': 'Afganistan', 'eu': 'Afganistan', 'fi': 'Afganistan', 'fr': 'Afghanistan', 'hu': 'Afganisztán', 'it': 'Afghanistan', 'ja': 'アフガニスタン', 'ko': '아프가니스탄', 'lt': 'Afganistanas', 'nl': 'Afghanistan', 'no': 'Afghanistan', 'pl': 'Afganistan', 'pt': 'Afeganistão', 'ro': 'Afganistan', 'ru': 'Афганистан', 'sk': 'Afganistan', 'sv': 'Afghanistan', 'th': 'อัฟกานิสถาน', 'uk': 'А Афганістан', 'zh': '阿富汗', 'zh-tw': '阿富汗'}
```

Function return_country:

```
print(return_country('af', 'fi'))
```

Output:

```
Afganistan
```

Comment: Added example code.